# FFmpeg get header size

Tags: c++, c, header, ffmpeg, avcodec

The question is to get header size from format context (AVFormatContext) in ffmpeg.

Now i'm using first packet position to get it:

```
avformat_open_input(&m_formatContext, m_openedFilePath.toStdString().c_str(), NULL, NULL);
//...
AVPacket packet;
if(av_read_frame(m_formatContext, &packet) >= 0)
    printf("Header size: %d", packet.pos); // First readed packet will be with header offset
```

Any better way to do it without reading frame?

Comment: do you mean reading ID3v2 tag? i got this problem too.. do you found any solution?